# Is cut() style binning available in dplyr?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, binning

Is there a way to do something like a `cut()` function for binning numeric values in a `dplyr` table?  I'm working on a large postgres table and can currently either write a case statement in the sql at the outset, or output unaggregated data and apply `cut()`.  Both have pretty obvious downsides... case statements are not particularly elegant and pulling a large number of records via `collect()` not at all efficient.

Comment: Not yet, but it's on the to do list.

Comment: I guess @hadley has something more in mind but this works: `BOD %.% group_by(cut(Time, 2)) %.% summarise(mean = mean(demand))`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204157/r-creating-a-categorical-variable-from-a-numerical-variable-and-custom-open-end

Comment: I think I've a answered this here in response to [Berk U](http://stackoverflow.com/users/568249/berk-u).

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204157/r-creating-a-categorical-variable-from-a-numerical-variable-and-custom-open-end/38960967#38960967

Comment: @hadley is this still planned?

Answer (score 46):

Just so there's an immediate answer for others arriving here via search engine,  the n-breaks form of `cut` is now implemented as the `ntile` function in `dplyr`:

```
> data.frame(x = c(5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3)) %>% mutate(bin = ntile(x, 2))
  x bin
1 5   2
2 1   1
3 3   2
4 2   1
5 2   1
6 3   2
```

Comment: What is there are `NA` in the columns being binned?

Comment: @vagabond it returns `NA`. Check out the example in the `ntile` documentation page.

Comment: Strictly, this is not a general `cut()` function for arbitrary breaks, it's only for ntiles (*"a rough rank, which breaks the input vector into ‘n’ buckets"*)

Answer (score 18):

I see this question was never updated with the `tidyverse` solution so I'll add it for posterity.

The function to use is `cut_interval` from the `ggplot2` package. It works similar to `base::cut` but it does a better job of marking start and end points than the `base` function in my experience because `cut` increases the range by 0.1% at each end.

```
data.frame(x = c(5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3)) %>% mutate(bin = cut_interval(x, n = 2))
  x   bin
1 5 (3,5]
2 1 [1,3]
3 3 [1,3]
4 2 [1,3]
5 2 [1,3]
6 3 [1,3]
```

You can also specify the bin width with `cut_width`.

```
data.frame(x = c(5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3)) %>% mutate(bin = cut_width(x, width = 2, center = 1))
  x   bin
1 5 (4,6]
2 1 [0,2]
3 3 (2,4]
4 2 [0,2]
5 2 [0,2]
6 3 (2,4]
```

Answer (score 11):

The following works with `dplyr`, assuming `x` is the variable we wish to bin:

```
# Make n bins
df %>% mutate( x_bins = cut( x, breaks = n )

# Or make specific bins
df %>% mutate( x_bins = cut( x, breaks = c(0,2,6,10) )
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me