# R: creating a categorical variable from a numerical variable and custom/open-ended/single-valued intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, intervals, categorical-data, binning

I often find myself trying to create a categorical variable from a numerical variable + a user-provided set of ranges.

For instance, say that I have a data.frame with a numeric variable `df$V` and would like to create a new variable `df$VCAT` such that:

- `df$VCAT` = 0 if `df$V` is equal to 0
- `df$VCAT` = 1 if `df$V` is between 0 to 10 (i.e. (0,10))
- `df$VCAT` = 2 is `df$V` is equal to 10 (i.e. [10,10])
- `df$VCAT` = 3 is `df$V` is between 10 to 20 (i.e. (10,20))
- `df$VCAT` = 4 is `df$V` is greater or equal to than 20 (i.e. [20,Inf])

I am currently doing this by hard coding the "scoring function" myself by doing something like:

```
df = data.frame(V = seq(1,100))
df = df %>% mutate(VCAT = (V>0) + (V==10) + 2*(V>10) + (V>=20))
```

I am wondering if there is an easier hacky way to do this in R, preferably using`dplyr` (so that I can chain commands). Ideally, I am looking for a short function that can be used in `mutate` that will take in the variable `V` and a vector describing the ranges such as `buckets`. 
Note that `buckets` may not be described in the best way here since it is not clear to me how it would allow users to customize the endpoints of the ranges.

Comment: Do you know about `cut()`? Check out `?cut` or perhaps even `Hmisc::cut2()`.

Comment: Do you want your function to take a vector plus `buckets` and return a data frame that looks like the result of the above? Or do you want a function that takes a vector and `buckets` that can be passed to `mutate`?

Comment: @jamieRowen preferably something that could be passed to `mutate`.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I wasn't aware of `cut` or `cut2` but they seem to do the trick. That said, I'm sure how to deal with points (e.g. an interval like [0,0]), and whether it can be incorporated with `mutate.`

Comment: @BerkU. I would initially have suggested cut but it doesn't deal with your final value in the way your questions suggests. `findInterval` seems to be a better suggestion here thanks to @Henrik EDIT: you can also pass it to mutate so I would suggest it solves your problem.

Comment: `car::recode` could be best here if you specify your "equal to" criteria first: `recode(df$V, "0=0; 100=5; 50=3; 0:10=1; 10:50=2; 50:100=4")` -- note: possible duplicate question -- see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5372896/2572423).

Comment: `df$VCAT2 <- cut(df$V, c(0,9.999,10,20,Inf), labels=F)` works just fine. @BerkU

Answer (score 1):

A way I bin numbers is to remove the remainder using the modulus opperator, `%%`.  E.g. to bin into groups of 20:

```
#create raw data
unbinned<-c(1.1,1.53,5,8.3,33.5,49.22,55,57.9,79.6,81,95,201,213)
rawdata<-as.data.frame(unbinned)

#bin the data into groups of 20
binneddata<-mutate(rawdata,binned=unbinned-unbinned %% 20)

#print the data
binneddata
```

This produces the output:

```
   unbinned binned
1      1.10      0
2      1.53      0
3      5.00      0
4      8.30      0
5     33.50     20
6     49.22     40
7     55.00     40
8     57.90     40
9     79.60     60
10    81.00     80
11    95.00     80
12   201.00    200
13   213.00    200
```

So 0 represents 0-<20, 20 represents 20-<40, 40 ,40-<60 etc. (of course divide the `binned` value by 20 to get sequential groups like in the original question)

**Bonus**

If you want to use the binned values as categorical variables in `ggplot` etc. by converting them into strings, they will order strangely, e.g. 200 will come before 40, because '2' comes before '4' in the alphabet, to get around this, use the `sprintf` function to create leading zeros. (the `3` in `%03d` should be the number of digits you expect the longest number to be):

```
#convert the data into strings with leading zeros
binnedstring<-mutate(binneddata,bin_as_character=sprintf('%03d',binned))

#print the data
binnedstring
```

giving the output:

```
   unbinned binned bin_as_character
1      1.10      0              000
2      1.53      0              000
3      5.00      0              000
4      8.30      0              000
5     33.50     20              020
etc.
```

If you want to have `000-<020`, create the upper bound using arithmetic and concatenate using the paste function:

```
#make human readable bin value
binnedstringband<-mutate(
    binnedstring,
    nextband=binned+20,
    human_readable=paste(bin_as_character,'-<',sprintf('%03d',nextband),sep='')
)

#print the data
binnedstringband
```

Giving:

```
   unbinned binned bin_as_character nextband     human_readable
1      1.10      0              000       20           000-<020
2      1.53      0              000       20           000-<020
3      5.00      0              000       20           000-<020
4      8.30      0              000       20           000-<020
5     33.50     20              020       40           020-<040
etc.
```

Comment: You can get the binned value directly with `(unbinned %/% 20) * 20`. Or `unbinned - (unbinned %% 20)`. These are the base quotient and remainder operators (for integers). Of course this only works if all bins are equal-size, i.e. not cut() with arbitrary breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut()`, already:

```
df$VCAT2 <- cut(df$V, c(0,9.999,10,20,Inf), labels=F)
```

Notice the trick I pull to define a very small bin at 10:

- (and if you need that bin to be infinitesimally narrow, use `10 - 10*.Machine$double.eps`)
- you can manually define your desired labels '(0,10)','[10,10]',(10,20), [20,Inf]' with the `cut(..., labels)` argument.