# Aggregating data from value and count attributes

Tags: r, aggregate, classification, histogram

In R, I have a large list of large dataframes consisting of two columns, `value` and `count`. The function which I am using in the previous step returns the value of the observation in `value`, the corresponding column `count` shows how many times this specific value has been observed. The following code produces *one* dataframe as an example - however all dataframes in the list do have different values resp. value ranges:

```
d <- as.data.frame(
  cbind(
    value = runif(n = 1856, min = 921, max = 4187),
    count = runif(n = 1856, min = 0, max = 20000)
  )
)
```

Now I would like to aggregate the data to be able to create viewable visualizations. This aggregation should be applied to all dataframes in a list, which do each have different value ranges. I am looking for a function, cutting the data into new values and counts, a little bit like a histogram function. So for example, for all data from a value of 0 to 100, the counts should be summated (and so on, in a defined interval, with a clean interval border starting point like 0).

My first try was to create a simple value vector, where each value is repeated in a number of times that is determined by the `count` field. Then, the next step would have been applying the `hist()` function without plotting to obtain the aggregated values and counts which can be defined in the `hist()`'s arguments. However, this produces too large vectors (some Gb for each) that R cannot handle anymore. I appreciate any solutions or hints!

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand your question correctly, but this might solve your problem or at least point you in a direction. I make a list of data-frames and then generate a new column containing the result of applying the `binfunction` to each dataframe by using `map`from the `purrr` package.

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- d2 <- tibble(
  value = runif(n = 1856, min = 921, max = 4187),
  count = runif(n = 1856, min = 0, max = 20000)
)

d <- tibble(name = c('d1', 'd2'), data = list(d1, d2))

binfunction <- function(data) {
  data %>% mutate(bin = value - (value %% 100)) %>% 
    group_by(bin) %>% 
    mutate(sum = sum(count)) %>% 
    select(bin, sum)
}

d_binned <- d %>% 
  mutate(binned = map(data, binfunction)) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(name, bin) %>% 
  slice(1L)

d_binned
#> Source: local data frame [66 x 3]
#> Groups: name, bin [66]
#> 
#> # A tibble: 66 x 3
#>     name   bin      sum
#>    <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1    d1   900 495123.8
#>  2    d1  1000 683108.6
#>  3    d1  1100 546524.4
#>  4    d1  1200 447077.5
#>  5    d1  1300 604759.2
#>  6    d1  1400 506225.4
#>  7    d1  1500 499666.5
#>  8    d1  1600 541305.9
#>  9    d1  1700 514080.9
#> 10    d1  1800 586892.9
#> # ... with 56 more rows

d_binned %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = bin, y = sum, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]
See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204157/r-creating-a-categorical-variable-from-a-numerical-variable-and-custom-open-end/38960967#38960967) for my inspiration for the binning. It bins the data in groups of 100, so e.g. bin 1100 represents 1100 to <1200 etc. I imagine you can adapt the `binfunction` to your needs.